# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error on putting a Asp.net MVC web api project to Docker container

Tags: asp.net-mvc, docker, iis, dockerfile

I'm trying a lift and shift of a Asp.Net MVC Web Api project to a docker container. I am successfully able to build and deploy the project but on pinging the site i get a   HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

The logs detailed by the container are as below  :

HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
  The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data
for the page is invalid.

Detailed Error Information:

```
Module&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;IIS Web Core
Notification&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Unknown
Handler&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Not yet determined
Error Code&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;0x8007000d
Config Error&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

Config File   \?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\web.config

```
Requested URL&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;http://localhost:80/
Physical Path&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
Logon Method&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Not yet determined
Logon User&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Not yet determined
Config Source:
   -1:
0:
```

More Information:
  This error occurs when there is a problem reading the configuration file for
the Web server or Web application. In some cases, the event logs may contain
more information about what caused this error.
  View more information »

The dockerfile is as structured like this

```
# escape=`
FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework:4.7.2-sdk-windowsservercore-ltsc2019 AS builder

WORKDIR C:\src
COPY . .
RUN nuget restore Solutions\*.Web.sln 
RUN msbuild MyApp.csproj /p:OutputPath=c:\out /p:Configuration=Dev    

# app image
FROM microsoft/aspnet:4.7.2-windowsservercore-ltsc2016
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';"]

ENV APP_ROOT=C:\inetpub\wwwroot `
    APP_LOGS=C:\logs `
    COLLECTOR_CONFIG_PATH="w3svc-collectors.json"    
WORKDIR ${APP_ROOT}

RUN powershell remove-item C:\inetpub\wwwroot\iisstart.*

RUN powershell -Command Add-WindowsFeature NET-WCF-HTTP-Activation45
RUN Import-Module WebAdministration; `
    Set-ItemProperty 'IIS:\AppPools\DefaultAppPool' -Name processModel.identityType -Value LocalSystem; 

VOLUME ${APP_LOGS}
COPY --from=builder C:\out\IIsStartup.ps1 /
ENTRYPOINT ["powershell", "/IIsStartup.ps1"]

COPY --from=builder C:\out\_PublishedWebsites\ ${APP_ROOT}
EXPOSE 80




<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"/>
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="false"/>
    <add key="System" value="local"/>   
    <add key="TraceSwitch" value="All"/>
  </appSettings>
  <!--
    For a description of web.config changes see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
      </system.Web>
  -->
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"/>
    <trace enabled="true" requestLimit="1000" localOnly="false"/>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.7.1" debug="true">
      <assemblies>
        <!--Application Insights: add System.Runtime assembly to resolve PCL dependencies-->
        <add assembly="System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7" executionTimeout="3600"/>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <httpModules/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules/>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit"/>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit"/>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"/>
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler"/>
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
      <!--<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />-->
    </handlers>
    <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true"/>
    <httpCompression>
      <dynamicTypes>
        <!-- TODO Geht f??r application/json nicht und ist statt dessen ??ber CompressFilterAttribute gel??st. Sollte noch mal analysiert werden -->
        <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="application/json; charset=utf-8" enabled="true"/>
      </dynamicTypes>
    </httpCompression>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".woff"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/x-woff"/>
    </staticContent>
    <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" existingResponse="PassThrough"/>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="RemoveIllegalCharacters">
          <match url="(.*)(&quot;|%22)(.*)"/>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}{R:3}"/>
        </rule>
        <!-- Do not activate remove trailing slash rule, otherwise we have sometimes an endless redirect after login -->
        <!--<rule name="RemoveTrailingSlashRule1" stopProcessing="true" enabled="false">
          <match url="(.*)/$" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
        </rule>-->
        <rule name="Remove Version from static files" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(styles|scripts|images)/(.+);v[0-9]+\.(css|js|gif|png|jpg|ico)"/>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}/{R:2}.{R:3}"/>
        </rule>
        <rule name="EnforceLowerCase" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="[A-Z]" ignoreCase="false"/>
          <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{URL}}"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.OData" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.8.4.0" newVersion="5.8.4.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.Edm" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.8.4.0" newVersion="5.8.4.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Spatial" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.4.0" newVersion="5.6.4.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.Services.Client" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.8.4.0" newVersion="5.8.4.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AI.Agent.Intercept" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.7.0" newVersion="2.0.7.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.3.0.0" newVersion="5.3.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocol.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.0.40306.1554" newVersion="1.0.40306.1554"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Xml" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.4.0" newVersion="5.2.4.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="StackExchange.Redis.StrongName" publicKeyToken="c219ff1ca8c2ce46" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.2.6.0" newVersion="1.2.6.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.6.0" newVersion="5.2.6.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.3.0.0" newVersion="5.3.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.3.0.0" newVersion="5.3.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.3.0.0" newVersion="5.3.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.19.8.16603" newVersion="3.19.8.16603"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Platform" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.19.8.16603" newVersion="3.19.8.16603"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="ExcelDataReader" publicKeyToken="93517dbe6a4012fa" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.4.2.0" newVersion="3.4.2.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="ExcelDataReader.DataSet" publicKeyToken="93517dbe6a4012fa" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.4.2.0" newVersion="3.4.2.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.0.3.0" newVersion="1.0.3.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.3.1" newVersion="4.0.3.1"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.7.0" newVersion="5.2.7.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data.SQLite" publicKeyToken="db937bc2d44ff139" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.0.110.0" newVersion="1.0.110.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework codeConfigurationType="CheckMyBus.DataAccess.MSSQL.EFConfiguration, CheckMyBus.DataAccess.MSSQL">
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v12.0"/>
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="0">
      <listeners>
        <add name="myAppInsightsListener" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener.ApplicationInsightsTraceListener, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener"/>
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

Comment: We need to see your web.config.

Comment: added a web.config

Comment: You used URL rewrite rules in `web.config` so you have to manually execute the MSI package for URL Rewrite module while building the Docker image. That's why you get 500.19 right now, as IIS URL Rewrite is missing inside the container.

Comment: That worked...awesome

Comment: It worked the first time but on rebuilding the site is unreachable.. any insight what would cause it